# How to take EBS snapshot in Boto3 only for running instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, snapshot

I am currently migrating the automated EBS snapshot from a Bash script to Python Boto3. In the original Bash shell, the script was just one line below:

```
ec2-describe-instances --filter "instance-state-code=16" | grep "vol-" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -n 1 -t ec2-create-snapshot -d "automated daily backup"
```

instance state code 16 refer to the running EC2 instances. I am new to Boto3, I have searched up everywhere the closest I can find is to taking snapshots of attached volumes, but that is not good enough as the stopped instances will still be snapshot every night despite nothing is changed on its EBS volumes.

Comment: *"stopped instances will still be snapshot every night despite nothing is changed on its EBS volumes."*  Note for what it's worth:  snapshots of unused volumes should also not cost anything additional, if you already  have snapshots stored.  Taking consecutive snapshots of unchanged volumes does not store any new snapshot data, since snapshots of the same volume are deduplicated before storage.  You'll also find that these snapshots are also completed very quickly, for the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With boto3, you can create [a filter](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.instances) for the ec2 resource, where you get only the running instances. From the resulting list of instances, iterate over each of them, and check their [`block_device_mappings`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.block_device_mappings).

You can get the volume-id from the above dictionary. Now, all you need to do is [create a snapshot](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_snapshot).

A rough code would be:

```python
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
for instance in ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{
        'Name': "instance-state-name",
        'Values': ["running"]
    }]
):
    for device in instance.block_device_mappings:
        ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId=device.get('Ebs').get('VolumeId'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your boto question, but I notice you are using the old-style command-line interface. These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) that has some great capabilities.

For example, this command will list the Volume ID for all EBS volumes attached to instances:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.VolumeId --output text
```

You could then add a filter to only show *running* instances:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.VolumeId --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --output text
```

Then you could put it *within* another command to snapshot volumes of *running* instances:

```
aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id `aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.VolumeId --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --output text`
```

No strange awk/grep commands required!